# getIpAddress() method returns integer representation of IPv4?

Tags: android, android-wifi, connectivity

In the below code i am tryin to get the `IP` of he network, but wht i get from `info.getIpAddress();` is

```
-25576378
```

why? and what is this?

**Code**

```
WifiInfo info = mWiFiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid;
int strength = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(info.getRssi(), 5);
String unit = WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS;
int ip_add = info.getIpAddress();
int speed = info.getLinkSpeed();
```

Comment: That isn't an "encrypted" IP; it's the four bytes of the IP address expressed as a four-byte integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this method to get the ip string:

```
private static String getIpAddress(WifiInfo wifiInfo) {
    String result;
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

    result = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ip & 0xff), (ip >> 8 & 0xff), (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
            (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

    return result;
}
```

`wifiInfo.getIpAddress()` returns an integer. This is possible, because **an IPv4-address contains 4 bytes** (f.e. 192.168.255.2 ==> 4 times 1 byte), just like an **integer consumes 4 byte** in Java/Android. By shifting the given integer number, you can determine each of the ip's byte values.

Comment: Will this work both on big endian and little endian processors?

Comment: @begemotv2718 With Android/Java, we are not working on system or assembler instruction level, but in a virtual machine, that hides hardware differences by an abstraction layer. So there should not be any difference between little or big endian architecture. On the other hand, a similiar function in C(++) might have differences here.